# Generate an image of a database' scehma with FK-PK relations as arros

Tags: database, data-visualization, diagram, modeling

I have the SQL DDL commands to create a database (`CREATE TABLE etc. etc.`) with some Foreign Key - Primary Key inter-table constraints.

Now, I want to generate an image which looks something like this:

[image]

That is, for every table, there's a listing of its name, its size (or a comment), and its column names (without the type); and single- or multi-column FK-PK relations are marked with an arrow connector, or split-ends arrow connector.

Required features:

- Gratis
- Produces either a high-resolution image or some vectorized format

Desired features:

- Libre license
- Supports customizing the output format, visually (colors, connector behavior, spacing)
- Supports customizing the output format, content-wise (e.g. displaying the data types, marking the primary key fields differently)
- Exports both images, SVGs and Libreoffice Draw / Visio / Dia files

Notes:

- It can be web-based, I don't mind.
- I can adapt my DDL to whichever dialect the tool supports - PostgreSQL, MySQL, MS-SQL, MonetDB, whatever. So the tool can be "fussy". I can even enter the field details and the constraints manually if push comes to shove.

Comment: Why free? and have you tried mysql workbench? did that fail to meet your needs?

Comment: @JonScott einpoklum seems to look for a file-based approach, not a tool that connects to a database to reverse-engineer DDL ("I have the SQL DDL commands to create a database"). Can MySQL Workbench do that?

Comment: MySQL Workbench - no - you have to create the database and then it can draw the diagram